# Phrases to describe different conditions

Tags: phrases, comparatives

For example, I measure test scores for different groups of students. When I present the results, should I say:

> Here are test scores with respect to different student groups.

Or:

> Here are test scores differentiated by student groups.

In fact, neither seems natural to me. Is there any better way of saying this?

Comment: The best alternative might be **of**: *Here are **the** test scores **of** different student groups.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural phrasing for similar contexts would be...

> *Here are the test scores **grouped by** [student nationality, or whatever].*

...but OP's categorisation system already includes the word "group", so to avoid sounding clumsy he should simply omit the word before "by"...

> *Here are the test scores **by** student group.*

Note that "grouped" is *always* optional in such constructions, but it's usually better included.

Taking the pedantic line, ***grouped by*** may be more appropriate if *individual* student test results are presented in a list containing a separate section for each group, and plain ***by*** if the *only* values shown are totals/averages for each group.

Answer (score 0):

What about "Here are the test scores for each student group" ?